# Postgresql SERIALIZABLE transaction make queue

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, race-condition, typeorm

I am using `typeorm` with database `postgresql`.

The specific route, needs transactions on high-load web app:

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { getManager } from 'typeorm';

const router = Router();

router.post('/apply', async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    await getManager().transaction('SERIALIZABLE', async (txManager) => {
        /* Many selects, inserts here */
    });
});
```

But if there is two simultaneous requests, the one request will errored with the message `could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions`.

How to prevent this? Maybe handle every request one-by one? But I don't know how to do this. Maybe there is some other ways to do transactions, but I have read documentation and didn't find anything for this.

Answer (score 0):

With the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, you don't prevent serialization errors, but you repeat the transaction if such an error occurs.